# Java JAXB - get intended output

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to get an XML ile in a form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<image>
    <lines>
        <line id="a">
            <coordinates x="297" y="44"/>
            <coordinates x="302" y="117"/>          
        </line >
        <line id="b">
            <coordinates x="42" y="111"/>
            <coordinates x="48" y="131"/>
            <coordinates x="39" y="142"/>           
        </line >
    </lines>
</image>
```

I have two classes: LineWrapper and Line:

LineWrapper:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "image")
public class LineWrapper {

    private List<Line> lines;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "lines")
    @XmlElement(name = "line")
    public List<Line> getLines() {
        return lines;
    }
    (...)
}
```

Line:

```
public class Line{
    (...)
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="x")
    public List<Integer> getxList() {
        return xList;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="y")
    public List<Integer> getyList() {
        return yList;
    }   
}
```

What I get with such annotation is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<image>
    <lines>
        <line id="a" x="297 302" y="44 117"/>
        <line id="b" x="44 48 39" y="111 131 142"/>
    </lines>
</image>
```

How do I make an extra tag 'coordinates' for an attribute pair of x and y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Coordinates` class holding the x and y values :

```
public class Coordinates{
    (...)

    private int x;
    private int y;


    @XmlAttribute(name="x")
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="y")
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    } 


}
```

Then modify your `Line` class to use a list of this as an element, rather that owning x and y values :

```
public class Line{
    (...)

    private List<Coordinates> coordinatesList = new ArrayList<Coordinates>;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "coordinates")
    public List<Coordinates> getCoordinatesList() {
        return coordinatesList;
    }



}
```

Of course you will have to create proper `Coordinates` objects (setter methods are missing in this example), and populate `Line` objects with them.